# Split element of xml node to return as json

Tags: php, xml, json

I am stuck with xml where one of the nodes lumps all the information together and I need to split these out into 3 separate objects.  Now it is Description - Color, Size.  So I know I can use the `-` and `,` characters to split on and then handle them that way.  I was able to split out the description [0] but now I am confused how to grab the [1] and [2] part of that split.  The part after the `-` and then another split for the `,`

I am converting xml into json with something like this :

The xml :

```
<Groups>
 <Group>
   <Item>
     <Description>One Item - Color: Black, Size: 9</Description>
   </Item>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <Item>
      <Description>Two Item - Color: White, Size: 11</Description>
    </Item>
  </Group>
</Groups>
```

The php :

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
  $items = count($xml->Groups->Group->Item);
  for ($i=0;$i<$items;$i++)
{
        if ($i) {
        $descriptions = $descriptions . '<br>' ;}
        $descriptions = $descriptions  .  $xml->Groups->Group->Item[$i]->Description[0];
        $descriptions = preg_split("/-/", $descriptions);
        $descriptions = $descriptions[0];

    }

$json = '{'. '"Description": "'.$descriptions.'",'.'}';
```

and then if `var itemDesc = json.Description;`

That variable will return:

`One Item  <br> Two Item  <br >`

How can I then get the next two parts from that split.  I was trying stuff like:

```
$color = $descriptions[1];
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please do NOT try manually tokenizing either XML or JSON, or generating -- use proper XML parser, JSON writer; otherwise you will end up with missing encoding (things suddenly fail for some content). There are lots of libs for handling both on PHP, just use those at low-level, implement conversion logic

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Can you possibly provide some further reading? I dont really understand what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: I re-read code, so you are properly using simple-xml parser so that's good (I mistook it for using regexps). But what I think you should consider is using a JSON writer/generator package to format output: this will allow you to use JSON arrays (instead of String with comma-separate values), making it easier for client. It will also ensure that characters like double-quote and linefeeds are escape in JSON String: if they are not, result is invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to split/explode/parse the description string inside of that code-block, you will likely make it very complicated. The first idea was to create a function that can parse the string and returns some array with the values, but then I thought this would be much more nice:

```
$item = new Item('Two Item - Color: White, Size: 11');

$item->getName(); # Two Item
$item->getProps(); # array( Color => White, Size => 11)
```

You can then use this object whenever it suits you. The parsing is done like this:

1. Divide into the part before the `-` and after.
2. Parse the second part for properties: Name + Value.
3. If anything fails, throw an exception.

The following code does this, the checking is pretty strict which I think is good to start with so you find errors in your specification early:

```
private function initFromText($description)
{
    list($this->name, $propText) = explode(' - ', $description, 2) + array('','');

    $propToken = '([a-z]+): (.*?)(, |$)';
    $offset = 0;

    while($r = preg_match("~$propToken~i", $propText, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset))
    {
        list($full, $name, $value) = $matches;
        if ($full[1] !== $offset || isset($this->props[$name[0]]))
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid Description given ("%s").', $description));
        $this->props[$name[0]] = $value[0];
        $offset += strlen($full[0]);
    }
    // all consumed?
    if (strlen($propText) !== $offset)
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid Description given ("%s").', $description));
}
```

Then it came to my attention that you can simplify your iteration as well, see the following, it should give you the idea:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
foreach($xml->xpath('Group/Item') as $i => $item)
{
    $description = (string) $item->Description;
    printf("%d: %s\n", $i, $description);
    $item = new Item($description);
    var_dump($item->getName(), $item->getProps());
}
```

[Full Example Code](https://gist.github.com/1343367)